# LINQ: How to use a variable field list in an orderBy clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm working on a system which stores an orderBy clause as a comma-separated string in a database.

This string can contain 0-3 elements.

Is there an elegant way to write a Linq query which would handle this, without resorting to a case statement?

Here's the gist of what I'm trying to do:

```
var instruments = from i in db.Instruments
                  orderby "Field1, Field2, Field3"
                  select i;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usually, I will recommend to you [Dynamic LINQ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/)

Then

```
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
..
var instruments = db.Instruments.OrderBy("Field1").ThenBy("Field2");
```

You can also create own extensions, as described [**HERE**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet).